Css mask-image corner pixelated
I've tried to create a curved box using mask-image property. I've achieved what
i need but the issue is that the corner looks pixelated. Any solutions for this.



.shape {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f00;
  mask-image: radial-gradient( circle 100px at 0 0, transparent 0, transparent 50px, black 21px);
}
<div class="shape">
</div>



Demo fiddle
Here is the code
    .shape{
     width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f00;
    mask-image: radial-gradient(
      circle 100px at 0 0,
      transparent 0,
      transparent 50px,
      black 21px
    );
}


sooraj s pillai, @visualVim: Please prefer to include working snippets - external examples should be complementary or a last resort, e.g. if the example code exceeds SO character limits. You may accidentally delete external snippets, making a question or answer less helpful for future users.

The solution is to use SVG as svgs don't rely on pixels like mask-image does, it relies on math/geometry. see vector graphics to understand.


.shape{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 74.877 74.877"><path d="M74.612 0c.65 24.955.082 49.918.265 74.877H0C38.566 72.93 73.975 39.213 74.612 0z" fill="%23ea3323"/></svg>');
}
<div class="shape"></div>




note that even with 500px width/height it does not pixelate

The thing is that you will have to create the svgs or use from the web

create the svg
convert to svg to data uri


You can "smooth" the gradient:


.shape {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f00;
  mask-image: radial-gradient( circle 100px at 0 0, transparent 0, transparent 50px, black 51px, black 21px);
}
<div class="shape">
</div>



